# what all access permission are required for prisma orm

Tags: nestjs, prisma, prisma2

I'm integrating prisma with nestjs
I want to know all the basic database user permissions required for prisma commands like migrate i.e. pull/push/deploy/dev etc.

We do not wish to give complete admin access and only wish to assign a few roles/permissions to user to perform basic CRUD tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the permissions which is required for `prisma migrate`

- PostgreSQL - The user must be a super user or have CREATEDB privilege.
- MySQL - Database user must have CREATE, ALTER, DROP, REFERENCES ON *.* privileges.
- SQL Server - The user must be a site admin or have the SERVER securable.

You can know more about it here: [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#shadow-database-user-permissions)